# Shapes in tf.test.compute_gradient_error

Tags: tensorflow

In addition to 2 tensors, tf.test.compute_gradient_error takes two shapes. Why are they required? Why can't we just evaluate the tensors and calculate their shapes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was written very early in TensorFlow's development, at a point where shape information was not associated with Tensors. Since it's not useful in model code, updating it for usability was never a priority.